# Create calculated field on custom record in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm looking for a way to create "calculated" field that would populate a value to a field.
At minimum I need to display a value in a numeric field on VIEW and EDIT user event.

Pseudocode:

```
if (record_in_view || record_in_edit) 
execute saved search;
calculate value based on saved search;
display value in a field;
```

At best I would like that field to display a value just like "built" field does on a Transaction > Work Order record does. It displays a value on VIEW user event but is also available as a value in Saved Search both as a filter and as a column. 
So far I can only achieve it on EDIT user event but when I try to do it on VIEW I get no value populated.

Comment: Using a calculated field within a saved search, either as column or as filter, won't be possible. Add a field in the during the UserEvent.VIEW, will be possible. So far how did you achieve it for the `edit` mode?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the record.submitFields to achieve in view mode in your beforeLoad UE